# Group and count active record Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables, `users` and `votations`, in votations have two fields `win_id` and `user_id`.
I need create query in active record with `win_id` (votation) and `id` (users).

My sql query like this: 
`Select users.name, Count(votations.win_id) from votations Inner Join users ON vontations.win_id = users.id Group By users.name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an association in `Violation` like this:

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "win_id"
```

Then this should do it:

```
Violation.joins(:user).group("users.name").count
```

It will give you a hash with the user name as the key and the count as the value.

If you don't have that association and don't want it, then change the `joins()` to this:

```
joins("JOIN users ON violations.win_id = users.id")
```

Comment: Awesome ! Votation.joins(:win).group("users.name").count THX BRO !

Answer (score 0):

The clearest way may be to just use `find_by_sql` ([docs here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql)):

```
User.find_by_sql("Select users.name, Count(votations.win_id) from votations Inner Join users ON vontations.win_id = users.id Group By users.name")
```